# Python Datetime - find semi-months periods for a date or 2-weeks period for a date

Tags: python, datetime, period

Similarly to checking which week is a date I want to check which semi-month period is a date using datetime in python?  I know we can use pd.offsets.SemiMonthEnd() but that's not what I am looking for.  Is there a function similarly to dt.week that will return the semi-month period the date is in?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware if there are such functions, but you can use this code:

```py
from calendar import monthrange
import datetime

today = datetime.date(2020, 6, 3)

# Two-weeks period for a date:
week_number = today.isocalendar()[1]
two_weeks_period_number = week_number // 2 + 1
print('Two-weeks period:', two_weeks_period_number)

# Number of semi-months for a date:
days_in_month = monthrange(today.year, today.month)[1]
semi_months_period_number = 2 * today.month - int((today.day / days_in_month) < .5)
print('Semi-months period:', semi_months_period_number)
```

Output:

```
Two-weeks period: 12
Semi-months period: 11
```

Comment: Thank you . This is helpful.